# ubuntu 14.04 default firewall rules

Tags: server, firewall, iptables, default

I would like to know exactly which scripts are responsible for default iptables rules (no ufw, no gufw) in Ubuntu Server 14.04.
After fresh installation even with ufw disabled (by default) there are such rules:

```
root@hv0:~# iptables -L -n
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:53
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:53
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:67
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:67

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.122.0/24     ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  192.168.122.0/24     0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:68
```

After installation on iptables-persistent and flushing all iptables rules and saved configuration once again those rules are back. How can I get rid of them?

Regards

Mikolaj

Comment: Any chance this is a VM? http://askubuntu.com/questions/201428/replacing-my-firewall-rules?rq=1